# Using timeStamp for idempotence?

Tags: javascript

I try to create a test where I send objects to a server, these objects have the same structure and they have a property whose value is a timestamp.

```
arrayItem: Item[] = [
    {ref: "toto", zone:"zone11", stamp: Date.now()},
    {ref: "tutu", zone:"zone22", stamp: Date.now()},
    {ref: "titi", zone:"zone33", stamp: Date.now()},
    {ref: "truc", zone:"zone44", stamp: Date.now()}
]
```

I would like to know how I can check if 2 timestamp or more are identical in order to create an alert and prevent sending to server.

to be clearer, if ever a timestamp is identical whatever the position of the object, I would like to generate an error. For now I try to create a nested loop

```
arrayItem: Item[] = [
        {ref: "toto", zone:"zone11", stamp: 999999999}, 
        {ref: "tutu", zone:"zone22", stamp: 111111111},
        {ref: "titi", zone:"zone33", stamp: 777777777},
        {ref: "truc", zone:"zone44", stamp: 111111111}
]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to check if two values are the same? Because that's basic JavaScript; use `===`. Or is there more to the question?

Comment: Sorry for my english, I want to know if in the object array 2 or several timestamp are identical. I try to do that with a nested loop

Answer (score 0):

[`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns numbers so just compare them with [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) like this:

```js
const arrayItem = [
  { ref: "toto", zone: "zone11", stamp: Date.now() },
  { ref: "tutu", zone: "zone22", stamp: Date.now() },
  { ref: "titi", zone: "zone33", stamp: Date.now() },
  { ref: "truc", zone: "zone44", stamp: Date.now() },
];

const [item1, item2] = arrayItem;

console.log(item1.stamp === +item2.stamp);
```

Comment: They are already numbers; there's no need for the unary plus. Also, I'm pretty sure we already have a question about "how to check if two values are equal"...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I confused with `new Date`